# vector length vhdl as output, how can I know in advance what will it be?

Tags: vector, binary, entity, vhdl, string-length

in VHDL I have to specify in `entity` block what will be my output lenght, but how can I know in advance what it will be?
If I add two 9-bit vectors the output could be 10-bit vector but it could be 9-bit vector too. for ex: `"100100111" + "001001000" = "101101111"` but it could be a 10-bit vector when I do for ex: `"11110011" + "110001110" = "1010000001"`. So I don't know how can I manage these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, if you add two N-bit numbers, you need N+1 bits to store (or output) the result. That's it. eg:

```
111111111 + 111111111 = 1111111110
000000000 + 000000000 = 0000000000
```

So

```
100100111 + 001001000 = 0101101111
                        ^
                        |
```

Comment: thank you so much, my doubt was on the 10th bit and if the '0' would have been automatically added at the beginning. Thanks :)